# In PyCharm is there a way to unify the run and debug windows?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I often like to work with multiple monitors when coding in PyCharm on OSX.  It's nice to have an editor window(s) on monitor A, and debug tools in monitor B, so I don't have to switch windows as much and so the debug windows have more real estate.

I'll switch back and forth between `Run` and `Debug` modes, sometimes quickly, depending on the task at hand.  The main problem I find, is the tool windows for `Run` and `Debug` are separate.  I have to stagger the tool windows so I can select one or the other.  This requires an extra click and is an awkward arrangement on the screen.

Another option I have is to split the screen between `Run` and `Debug` tools, in which case I'm loosing real-estate.

Either way I find it's cumbersome to find the window I'm looking for.  Sometimes these are hiding on a separate hidden desktop so I have to take the time to find the desktop, open the desktop, then switch to the correct tool window.

Is there any option in PyCharm to merge these two windows, either as separate tabs on the same window, or some option to have them share the same console output window?

Comment: FYI, I'm running version PyCharm 2021.1.3 on OSX Catalina

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any option in PyCharm to merge these two windows

No. In the PyCharm nomenclature *Run* and *Debug* are *"tool windows"*, not just windows. You can open each *"tool window"* in its own window but you can't merge 2 *"tool windows"*.

Another thing are the "toolbars" of which you have 3, left, right and bottom. You can pin *"tool windows"* to the toolbars and they show like tabs but they are still separate and not merged, just tabs.

> The main problem I find, is the tool windows for Run and Debug are separate.

That's a PyCharm rule an there's no way around it. Each of those *"tool windows"* works as a separate application/plugin. They aren't meant to be merged. The windows don't have that functionality.

The easy way to do this is using the keyboard shortcuts, <kbd>Alt+4</kbd> or <kbd>Alt+5</kbd> takes you to *Run* or *Debug*, <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd> launches the *Run* config and switches focus to the *Run tool window*, same with <kbd>Shift+F9</kbd> for the *Debug tool window*.

If you right-click on the toolbar and choose `View Mode` `>` `Window` for both *tool windows* you can put them on the 2nd screen over each other. That gives you maximum real-estate with 1-keyboard stroke switch and running, but not tabbed clicking.

That's as good as it gets, you can't have both *tool windows* tabbed on a single window outside the toolbars.

> on a separate hidden desktop so I have to take the time to find the desktop, open the desktop, then switch to the correct tool window.

Having the 1-keystroke solution working would depend if the OS allows you to configure the Desktops to gain focus and come to the forefront if any of the windows in them have activity.

If not, an alternative would be a coinciding key bind where you set the Desktop containing the *Run* and *Debug* *"window toolbars"* to gain focus when you press <kbd>Alt+4</kbd>, <kbd>Alt+5</kbd>, <kbd>Shift+F9</kbd>, <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd>. Or changing the PyCharm shortcuts to coincide with the OS keyboard shortcuts that focus the designated Desktop.

Comment: If I place the Debug/Run tool windows on a separate monitor and separate virtual desktop and put them in 'Window' mode, I find the ^D (Debug) shortcut will neither activate the Tool window, nor switch to the virtual desktop containing the window.  If the Run window is on top it states on top.  This is the case even if the 'Activate Tool Window' option is set.  Interestingly, when I Stop debug mode, it quickly switches the virtual desktop and activates the tool window.  I just wish it would work on when I start it with ^D

Comment: @gmetzker I didn't test all the combinations. The above works **if** the tool window is opening for the 1st time, or **if** you `Shift+Esc` after each use (tested on Windows). ATM this is the closest possible to your problem statement, otherwise the alternative is to wait for [this FR](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55195) that's in active development.